# Solve using Fermat Theorem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$x^{86} ≡ 6 $ (mod 29)

I have the solution but don't understand it. Can someone write step by step instructions on how to do this type of questions.

See Question 1(b) for solution: http://palmer.wellesley.edu/~ivolic/pdf/Classes/MATH349CryptographyFall11/Solutions/349%20Crypto%20homework%203%20solutions.pdf

Comment: what's the first thing you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand how they got $x^2$ mod(29) in the link I posted

Comment: Since $86=84+2=3\cdot28+2$

Comment: $ 86 = 28\cdot 3 + 2\,$ so $\,x^{\large 86} = x^{\large 28\cdot 3 + 2} = (x^{\large 28})^{\large 3} x^{\large 2}\ \ $

Comment: Since $x^{28}\equiv 1 \pmod{29}$, you can replace $x^{28}$ with $1$ when working modulo 29.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is clear that $x\ne 0\ (\ mod \ 29\ )$ holds. So, due to Fermats
 theorem, we have $x^{28}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 29\ )$. So, we can conclude that
 $x^{84}=(x^{28})^3\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 29\ )$.

So, the eqaution simplifies to $x^2\equiv 6\ (\ mod\ 29\ )$ , which has the
 solutions $8$ and $21$.

Comment: how did you get 8 and 21?

Comment: Getting modular roots is not easy... for small numbers the answer is usually "by inspection", that is, by trying out the squares of the numbers. Note that the two answers sum to $29$ inevitably since $(29-x)^2=29(29-x) -29x +x^2 \equiv x^2 \bmod 29$.